# Audio spectrum visualization normalize loudness countour

Tags: signal-processing, spectrum

I've written an audio spectrum visualizer as you can see on the following screenshot. It works pretty well but the peaks are not really normalized. I think this is caused by this fact: [Equal-loudness contour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-loudness_contour).

Does anybody know how to get balanced peaks (like a horizontal line)?

Here is my code: https://github.com/frankred/openFrameworks-music-visualization/blob/master/ofApp.cpp

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you already know the equal-loudness contour, why not divide by it?

Comment: Do you know for sure if that is the problem why it is not more like a horinzontal line?

Comment: Whatever the cause, the OP wants to get balanced peaks, probably for a good visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

Is your horizontal scale linear frequency? Usually, a log frequency scale (i.e., equal dimension per octave-based) is more effective than linear in illustrating spectral distribution of audio.

Comment: I'm not really sure about what you mean. I get this spectrum out of FFT (see function fft::powerSpectrum on file https://github.com/frankred/openFrameworks-music-visualization/blob/master/fft.cpp)